# Querying the result of an previous SQL query, using a HTML form and PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to get this to work. Now, i'll explain it a bit better here.

What i'm trying to do is, when the user types something into a form it returns the result of the query, then using the results from **that** query, carry out *another* query on them. I'm using PHP and an oracle database.

For instance: currently I've a database full of recipes and their ingredients; and I have a form that a user can enter an ingredient into. In this example, it's bacon.

[image]

That works just fine. However, what i'm having difficulty achieving is when the user enters *another* ingredient, the results of the current table there and further queried. Say I enter 'cheese', all the recipes containing bacon **AND** cheese are then queried and displayed.

This process is easily achieved in simple SQL, however like I saw i'm having difficulty transferring it to use a form.

Now, I've an idea the solution is either something to do with temporary tables, dynamic sql or a combination of the both.

Thank you in advance for any help regarding the matter.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}

function do_fetch($myeid, $s)
{
  print '<table border="1">';
  while ($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) {
    print '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $item) {
      print '<td>'.($item?htmlentities($item):'&nbsp;').'</td>';
    }
    print '</tr>';
  }
  print '</table>';
  print '<br>';
}

// Create connection to Oracle
$c = oci_connect("system", "luigi98", "localhost/XE");

// Use bind variable
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT r.recipeTitle AS recipe
FROM RECIPES.recipe r
WHERE recipeID IN(
    SELECT r.recipeID
    FROM recipes.recipeIng il
    INNER JOIN RECIPES.ingredient i ON il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID 
    WHERE il.recipeID = r.recipeID
      AND i.ING = :eidbv)";
$s = oci_parse($c, $query);

$myeid = $name;
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":EIDBV", $myeid);
oci_execute($s);
do_fetch($myeid, $s);


// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($c);

?>
<p>Enter ingredient</p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: If you're looking to build an application, might I suggest a framework, such as Zend, CodeIgniter, or CakePHP? Using a framework will provide abstractions that handle the database connection stuff, and streamline the chaining of calls that you're looking to do.

Comment: Right now, you're only executing the query for a single ingredient.  So maybe you can store the ingredients in an array, and use another array to store the results from each query.  Then for each ingredient in your ingredients array you run the query and store the result in the results array.  I hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do that.

The easiest is probably to display your original ingredient(s) in the search box again and instruct the user to add more (separated by space, comma, etc.) ingredients if they want to.

Then you can explode your search terms on these characters and add a condition for every ingredient.